# token mismatch in phpmyadmin in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP when run `localhost/phpmyadmin`. It displays token mismatch.

I followed some posts related my issue in stackoverflow, but still i can't correct it.

What i did: In php.ini `;session.save_path = "N;/path""/tmp"` these edited to `session.save_path = "/tmp"` and clear cookies and restart. but still i can't get it.

My page look like this, please see this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkr3D.jpg

Please help me..

Comment: This is not a programming question, You'd have better luck at serverfault

Comment: Ports are block.. try to run it as admin

Comment: @bhushya: can you explain please?

Comment: Yeah i saw screenshot and it contains all required info in error .. read red lines..

Comment: @saina u got my point r8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw the Image
The **Port 80** is being used by any other existing application.

So, Either change the port for that application or

**How to change the mysql port for xampp?**

1. Stop the xampp server, if it is already running.
2. Edit the value to "port" in 
   xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

   port = 3306=>3307
   socket="/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"

and here also
Code:

The MySQL server

```
[ mysqld ] 
port =  3306=>3307
socket =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

1. Start mysql service